# Wrong result in throught loop array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I am new to JS and am having some difficulty with Array

I have the following answer from an AJAX request

```
Array
(
    [ct] => 3
    [company] => 143
    [employee] => 1
    [doc] => 23245221000160
)
Array
(
    [menssageI] => O CAMPO CPF DA LINHA 2 NÃO É NUMÉRICO
)
Array
(
    [menssageII] => CPF DA LINHA 2INVÁLIDO
)
```

When I have access to the result, it only returns me one letter
like

```
$var[0] A
$var[1] r
$var[2] r
```

I tried with JSON.parse and it didn't work either
Why does it happen? What am I doing wrong? And how can I access, for example, the key messageI

Comment: `json_encode()` not `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following answer from an AJAX request

That's the result of using `var_dump` in PHP.

**If** you're in control of the code producing that result, don't use `var_dump`, use `json_encode` so what you're sending back is valid JSON. (In fact, it looks like three calls to `var_dump`; you'll need to put those three arrays into some kind of structure and just do a single call to `json_encode`.)

Then on the receiving end, you'll be able to use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON into an object.

**If** you're **not** in control of the code producing that result, it's going to be a pain to work with. Simple ones like the ones you've quoted are relatively straightforward to parse (although you don't know what's a number and what's a string, you have to guess based on whether it consists of only digits etc.), but more complex ones will require a parser of some kind.

Comment: it workssss.. thank you very much

was having a huge problem with that. Best regards